# predict.MCMCglmm errors in R

Tags: r, predict, mcmc

I'm getting back into an old dataset, where I had multinomial mcmcglmm models. Understanding the posteriors for these models requires converting the formulas into predictions. I had been using' `predict()` in R in 2015-2016, and it was working in the following format, at that time:

`pred <- predict.MCMCglmm(model, marginal = model$Random$formula, interval="prediction")`

I'm now finding that the same line of code throws an error. To be specific: `Error in if (!grepl("hu|zi|za|multinomial", object$Residual$family[i])) { : 
  argument is of length zero`

I found this old communication indicating that it is because the `family` value is null, but when I use the solution `model$Residual$family<-rep("gaussian", nrow(model$X))`, I still get an error. This time it's `Error in if (nat == 0) { : argument is of length zero`

I am not understanding anything useful out of the traceback, but here it is just in case:

```
> 4. simulate.MCMCglmm(object = object, nsim = nrow(object$Sol), newdata = newdata, marginal = marginal, type = type, it = it, posterior = posterior, verbose = verbose)
> 3. simulate(object = object, nsim = nrow(object$Sol), newdata = newdata, marginal = marginal, type = type, it = it, posterior =
> posterior, verbose = verbose)
> 2. t(simulate(object = object, nsim = nrow(object$Sol), newdata = newdata, marginal = marginal, type = type, it = it, posterior =
> posterior, verbose = verbose))
> 1. predict.MCMCglmm(m1.Ed.all, marginal = m1.Ed.all$Random$formula, interval = "prediction")
```

I'm clearly missing something, but reading back through the documentation and googling has gotten me no further. I'm not even sure which argument is being referred to as length zero, here, because the `family` value is no longer blank. Although the fact that the error message changes suggests it does have to do with that value.

As an aside: if there's now a better, smoother way to plot predictions from a multinomial mcmcglmm I would be overjoyed to hear about it.